# Effective way to test if object is null

Tags: java, performance

What is better use in order to check if object is null.

To check if the object is null or to set a flag for it.
By saying better im looking for performance (faster and safer).

```
public class A
{

Object test;
boolean isTestObjectSet;

public A(Object test)
{
this.test = test;
isTestObjectSet = true;
}

public A()
{

}

public void doSomething()
{

if(test != null)
//do something

//VS

if(isTestObjectSet)
//do something


}
}
```

Comment: Java 8 has `Optional<Object>` for such cases. Performance was not the design reason, but one may assume that the compiler exploits the semantics somewhat. Especially the usage.

Comment: don't worry about micro performance issues like this. Write code as clearly as possible, and only worry about these kinds of things when you prove that there is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `isTestObjectSet` is just making things more complicated than they need to be. Just use `test != null`: it better conveys your intention *and* doesn't force you to keep this `isTestObjectSet` variable in-sync with whether or not `test` is set. There is *absolutely no* performance difference between the two variants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I didnt know how java checks for null object and I thought that maybe setting a flag will be better

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion - explicit checks (comparing to 'null') is faster, in terms not cluttering your code with many intermediary boolean variables.
Safer? Both of the checks are boolean checks, so it is always 'true'/'false' comparison.